# align absolute div with right edge of anothe div using angularjs directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to align right side of absolute div with right side of another div using angularjs directive. Code is almost working but children divs are a bit wider than parent and I am getting a wrong value of offsetWidth.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/witepo/9d8gq8r2/3/)

My directive:

```
app.directive('alignElementRight', function ($document) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        alignElementRight: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('alignElementRight', function (value) {
            console.log(value);

            var relEleme = $document.find('#' + value);
            var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + value));
            var elOffsetLeft = myEl[0].offsetLeft;
            var elOffsetTop = myEl[0].offsetTop;
            var elOffsetWidth = myEl[0].offsetWidth;

            console.log('main width:' + elOffsetWidth);

            var absElemOffsetWidth = element[0].offsetWidth;
            console.log('menu: ' + absElemOffsetWidth);

            var newOffsetLeft = Math.abs(elOffsetLeft + elOffsetWidth - absElemOffsetWidth);
            element.css({
                left: newOffsetLeft + 'px'
            });
        });


    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix would be to reset the bootstrap's negative margin settings for .row elements because that's what's causing all the mess (your calculations are good otherwise):

```
.row {
    margin: 0;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9d8gq8r2/4/